# Deploying a web app with Azure CLI messes up the last modified date on the files leading to caching failure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm deploying a WebGL application into Azure with Azure CLI using the command `az webapp deploy`. I noticed that after deploying a new version, the files were not being cached by Chrome (or any other browser).

After a lengthy investigation, I noticed that the Last-Modified header of the requests has been set to a time in the future.

Specifically, it looks like the time zone info has been lost and my current local time (GMT+3) has been interpreted as a GMT time, so if I built the app at 1 PM local time and immediately deployed it, the **Last-Modified** header would be at 1 PM GMT, i.e. three hours in the future. Thus, the browser would reload the file every time. Indeed, if I wait three hours, the caching suddenly starts to work because Last-Modified is now in the past. Additionally, if I manually modify LastWriteTime and LastWriteTimeUtc to 3 hours in the past on the files with PowerShell, the Last-Modified header changes accordingly and the caching works.

Any ideas on how I could get time zone info to transmit correctly through the deployment with azure cli?

Edit: Well, I ended up just adding a step to my build script that iterates over all the files in the build and reduces LastWriteTime and LastWriteTimeUtc on the files with PowerShell by the offset of the current TimeZone to Utc, so that when the build is deployed and the times change to GMT they match the present moment. It's not pretty but it will do.

Comment: there is no direct way to get the time zone info to transmit correctly through the deployment with Azure CLI.

Comment: the Last-Modified header during deployment using PowerShell with az webapp deploy. The Last-Modified header is typically determined by the web server based on the file's last modification timestamp.

Comment: but we can set a delay in deployment of the file

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy), I am able to deploy the files.

- Make sure to turn on `Basic auth` as shown in the below image.

AFAIK,  We cannot change the Last-Modified with Cli or Powershell. It Indicates the last time the is modified but we can set a delay in deployment of the file.

[image]

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group ResourceGroup --name AppName --src-path SourcePath --type war --async true
```

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group ResourceGroup --name AppName --src-path SourcePath --type static --target-path staticfiles/test.txt
```

[image]

[image]

- We can find the uploaded files in the Azure app service in Advanced Tools>>DebugConsole.

[image]